# Most powerful test for simple hypothesis for $N(0,\sigma^2)$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, inference

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ denote a random sample from density, $N(0,\sigma^2)$, Find the **most powerful test** for testing the simple hypothesis $H_0:\sigma= \sigma_0^2$ vs $H_1:\sigma=\sigma_1^2$ where $\sigma_1^2 >\sigma_0^2$.

I'm not really sure of the procedure here. My process so far has been to state the likelihood ratio:

$$ \frac{\prod \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}e^{(x_i^2/2\sigma_1^2)}}{\prod \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_0^2}}e^{(x_i^2/2\sigma_0^2)}} $$

Which I think then reduces to this:

$$(\frac{\sigma_1}{\sigma_0})^{-n/2} e^{{(1/2\sigma_0^2-1/2\sigma_1^2)}}\sum x_i^2 $$

Then try to obtain some sort of critical value $c$. I'm not sure how to get this.

Is the statistic of the test $\Sigma x_i^2 $? How do you use it to get the power? How are you sure that this is definitely the most powerful test? The chi-squared distribution is involved somehow I think - how does this come into it?

Comment: One way to do this is to use Neyman-Pearson lemma which indeed gives a test of the form $\sum X_i^2>c$. Are you familiar with the Neyman-Pearson approach?

Comment: Not really. Do you know any good articles i can read about this?

Comment: If $f$ is the joint pdf, then by N-P lemma a most powerful test rejects $H_0$ for large values of the likelihood ratio $f_{H_1}/f_{H_0}$. This reduces the rejection region to $\sum x_i^2 >c$. We find $c$ subject to some size restriction using the distribution of the test statistic $\sum X_i^2$ under $H_0$. If this is some sort of homework, suggest you add the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag.

Comment: It is difficult to see how your first expression reduces to the second, even after taking logarithms, so please check your algebra before you go any further.

Comment: Thanks! I've made some changes. Does this look right?

Comment: No, it's still incorrect.  (Proof: when all the $x_i=0,$ the ratio is nonzero but your formula gives $0.$) Start by taking logarithms and work from there. You might find the algebra to be simpler if you use the "precision" parameter $\phi = 1/\sigma^2$ instead.

Comment: Ok. Have i at least got the likelihood ratio correct?

Comment: Check the signs in the exponents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is six questions--and @StubbornAtom has done a good job outlining answers in one pithy comment.  There appear to be two obstacles to going further: one is doing the initial algebra and the other is conceptual.

---

**Let's deal with the algebra first,** because that's straightforward and doing it doesn't deprive you of the joy of discovery and learning the statistical concepts.

Begin with the Normal density function $$f_{\sigma}(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\, \sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)x^2 + \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\log \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)\right).$$

The repeated appearance of $1/\sigma^2$ as well as the exponential suggest (a) working with $\phi = 1/\sigma^2$ as the parameter and (b) taking the logarithm, which in these terms is

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(- \phi\, x^2  + \log \phi  + C\right)$$

where $C = \log (1/(2\pi))$ will soon disappear.

For $n$ iid data $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ the log likelihood therefore is the sum of the individual log probability densities

$$\Lambda(\phi; \mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2}\left(- \phi\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2  + n\log \phi + nC\right).$$

The log likelihood ratio for a pair of parameter values $\phi_1$ and $\phi_0$ is the difference

$$\operatorname{LLR}(\phi_1,\phi_0;\mathbf{x}) = \Lambda(\phi_1;\mathbf{x}) - \Lambda(\phi_0;\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2}\left(n\left(\log \phi_1 - \log \phi_0\right) - \frac{\phi_1-\phi_0}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right).$$

---

Here, now, are some guides to answering the remaining questions:

1. **The test statistic.** The data appear in the log likelihood ratio in the form $\sum x_i^2.$  This, therefore, is all you need to know about the data.
2. **The chi-squared distribution.** A Normal$(0,\sigma)$ variable has the same distribution as a standard Normal variable multiplied by $\sigma.$  By *definition,* the sum of squares of $n$ iid standard Normal variables has a $\chi^2(n)$ distribution.  Therefore $\sum x_i^2,$ when divided by $\sigma^2,$ must have a $\chi^2(n)$ distribution.
3. **How does the likelihood ratio determine a most powerful test?** The [Neyman-Pearson Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma) tells you how to test the simple hypothesis $H_0: \phi = \phi_0$ against the simple alternative $H_1: \phi=\phi_1.$

   - For a given $\phi_0,$ different alternatives $\phi_1 \lt \phi_0$ (which correspond to $\sigma_1 \gt \sigma_0$) don't change the test.  This is why the N-P lemma applies to your situation.
   - The N-P lemma implies the boundary of the critical region is where the test statistic equals some constant, say $c.$  The value of that constant determines the size of the test as well as its power curve.
   - Since this problem is being posed to you, you must already have learned the N-P lemma, whether or not you know it by that name.  Your notes and textbook therefore should be good resources for studying it.
4. **Computing power.** Any given value of $\phi$ determines $\sigma = 1/\sqrt{\phi}.$ Thus, by $(2),$ it completely determines the distribution of the test statistic.  Use this to compute the power of the test associated with the constant $c$ in $(3).$  By definition, the power for the alternative $\sigma_1$ is the chance that the test statistic will lie in the critical region and by $(2)$ and $(3)$ that's given by a chi-squared distribution.
5. **Why does this all work?**  The underlying concept is worked out in detail, with extensive illustrations, in my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/130772/919.  The *only* departure from the present question is that this explanation concerns the other alternative $\sigma_1 \lt \sigma_0$ -- but that's an inconsequential difference.